# Good practice to change a method signature

Tags: java, methods, refactoring

I have a situation where I declare a method say

```
public String getData(WebDriver driver, int iRowNumber)
```

I am calling this method from a number of other test case methods. Now I feel the necessity to change the number of parameters and include a third parameter. It is obviously going to throw error in all the previous test case methods. How do I handle this situation? I don't want to create another method with the same name and different number of arguments (Polymorphism) as I have to use the modified method in the previous test methods as well.

Is there a way by which I can take care of this?

Comment: your IDE should have a refactoring "change method signature* where you can add a new parameter and provide a default value which will be inserted at any existing invocation.

Comment: why not use Polymorphism? or you do not need the *old*   method, so there it is no reason to test it; or it is needed, then it would be no error to have both

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger because methods with same name and different parameters are *overloading* not polymorphism...

Comment: It's almost always a Very Bad Idea to invalidate a published API. Either create a new method, or better, a new type for your new functionality. If necessary, `@Deprecate` the old method or type, but don't remove it. If the API hasn't been published, then refactor away!

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I'm pretty sure the questions author used it meaning it otherwise (and my comment was directed to him - haven't used @TimothyTruckle).

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is to create a new method with three arguments:

```
public String getData(WebDriver driver, int iRowNumber, Object third)
```

This method should have a new logic. The old method should call a new method with default arg:

```
public String getData(WebDriver driver, int iRowNumber) {
    getData(driver, iRowNumber, DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```